# Finding height in a binary tree using a queueList

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with my getHeight() method, it is not returning the correct height for the tree. I really think the problem has something to do with my QueueList Class but I can not for the life of me solve the issue. I'm open to suggestions on how to better implement a Binary search. Below is my QueueList Class.

```
package lab5;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class QueueList<E> implements Queue<E> {
private Node<E> front;
private Node<E> rear;
private int size = 0;
public QueueList (E it){
    front = rear = new Node<E>(it);
    size++;
}
public QueueList(){
    front = rear = new Node<E>();
    size=0;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size==0;
}

public void enqueue(E it) {

        rear.setNext(rear);
        rear.setElement(it);
        size++;
    }



public void clear() {
    front=new Node<E>();
    rear=new Node<E>();
    front.setNext(null);
    rear.setNext(null);
    front.setNext(null);
    size=0;
}


public int size() {
    return size;
}

public E front() {
    return front.getElement();
}

public E dequeue() {
    Node<E> temp = front;
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    else{
        front = front.getNext();
        size--;
        return temp.getElement();

    }
}

}
```

Here is my Binary search tree class, all of my BSTNode Method works correctly so just assume that is not the issue.

```
package lab5;
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> {

private BSTNode root;

private int size;

public BinarySearchTree() {

    root = null;

    size = 0;

}

public BinarySearchTree(BSTNode node) {

    root = node;

    size = 1;

}

/**
 * searches for a node that contains it.
 * 
 * if it finds it, it returns that node
 * 
 * else it returns null
 * 
 * @param it
 *            - the element to look for
 * 
 * @return the node that contains it
 * 
 */

public BSTNode search(E it) {
    BSTNode<E> parent = null;
    BSTNode<E> child = null;
    BSTNode<E> node = root;
    while (node != null && node.getElement() != it) {
        parent = node;
        int compareResult = it.compareTo(node.getElement());
        if (compareResult < 0) {
            node = node.getLeft();
        } else {
            node = node.getRight();
        }
    }
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return node;
}

/**
 * determines if the tree contains the element
 * 
 * @return true if it is in the tree
 * 
 */

public boolean contains(E it) {
    return (search(it) != null);
}

/**
 * Add the element to the correct location
 * 
 * all elements to the left are less than the parent
 * 
 * all elements to the rights are greater than the parent
 * 
 * Do not allow duplicates
 * 
 * @param it
 *            the element to insert
 * 
 */

public void insert(E it) {
    BSTNode<E> newNode = new BSTNode<E>(it);
    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    BSTNode<E> parent = null;
    BSTNode<E> node = root;
    while (node != null) {
        parent = node;
        int compareResult = it.compareTo(node.getElement());
        if (compareResult < 0) {
            node = node.getLeft();
        } else if (compareResult > 0) {
            node = node.getRight();
        } else {
            // duplicate
            return;
        }
    }
    int res = it.compareTo(parent.getElement());
    if (res < 0) {
        parent.setLeft(newNode);
    } else {
        parent.setRight(newNode);
    }
    size++;
}

/**
 * Removes the node that contains it.
 * 
 * If the tree does not contain it, it prints that to
 * 
 * the user and does nothing else.
 * 
 * Otherwise it removes the node and maintains the
 * 
 * BST properties
 * 
 * if removing a node with two children, replace it
 * 
 * with its in order predecessor.
 * 
 * @param the
 *            element of the node you want to remove.
 * 
 */

public void remove(E it) {
    BSTNode<E> parent = null;
    BSTNode<E> child = null;
    BSTNode<E> node = root;
    // Find the node that contains it
    while (node != null && node.getElement() != it) {
        parent = node;
        int compareResult = it.compareTo(node.getElement());
        if (compareResult < 0) {
            node = node.getLeft();
        } else {
            node = node.getRight();
        }
    }
    if (node == null) {
        System.out.println("failed to find: " + it + " for removal");
        return;
    }
    if (node.isLeaf()) {
        if (parent == null) {
            root = null;
        } else if (it.compareTo(parent.getElement()) < 0) {
            parent.setLeft(null);
        } else {
            parent.setRight(null);
        }
    } else if (node.getLeft() == null) {
        child = node.getRight();
        swapElements(node, child);
        node.setLeft(child.getLeft());
        node.setRight(child.getRight());
    } else if (node.getRight() == null) {
        child = node.getLeft();
    } else {
        child = node.getLeft();
        parent = null;
        while (child.getRight() != null) {
            parent = child;
            child = parent.getRight();
        }
        if (parent == null) {
            swapElements(node, child);
            node.setLeft(child.getLeft());
        } else {
            swapElements(node, child);
            parent.setRight(child.getLeft());
        }
    }
    size--;
}

/**
 * Returns the height of the tree
 * 
 * if tree is empty, height is -1
 * 
 * if tree only has one node, height is 0
 * 
 * @return the integer height of the tree
 *
 * 
 * 
 */

public int getHeight() {
    int height = -1;
    QueueList<BSTNode> q = new QueueList<BSTNode>();
    if (root == null) {
        return height;
    }
    q.enqueue(root);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        int nodeCount = q.size();
        height++;
        while (nodeCount > 0) {
            BSTNode<E> node = q.dequeue();
            if (node.hasLeft()) {
                q.enqueue(node.getLeft());
            }
            if (node.hasRight()) {
                q.enqueue(node.getRight());
            }
            nodeCount--;
        }
    }
    return height;
}

/**
 * Helper method
 * 
 * For removal you need to swap elements of nodes
 * 
 * @param node1
 *            , node2 the nodes whose contents you are swapping
 * 
 */

private void swapElements(BSTNode node1, BSTNode node2) {
    BSTNode temp = null;
    temp.setElement(node1.getElement());
    node1.setElement(node2.getElement());
    node2.setElement(temp.getElement());
}

/**
 * prints each level of the tree on its own line
 * 
 * use your Queue class
 * 
 */

public void printLevelOrder() {
    QueueList<BSTNode> q = new QueueList<BSTNode>();
     q.enqueue(root);//You don't need to write the root here, it will be written in the loop
     while (q.size() > 0)
     {
       BSTNode n = q.dequeue();
       System.out.println(n.toString()); //Only write the value when you dequeue it
        if (n.hasLeft())
        {
            q.enqueue(n.getLeft());//enqueue the left child
        }
        if (n.hasRight())
        {
           q.enqueue(n.getRight());//enque the right child
        }
     }
}



/**
 * prints the tree in a depth-first fashion
 * 
 * use your Stack class
 * 
 */

public void printByDepth() {
    StackList<BSTNode> s = new StackList<BSTNode>();
    s.push(root);
    while (s.isEmpty() == false) {
        BSTNode x = s.pop();
        if (x.getRight() != null)
            s.push(x.getRight());
        if (x.getLeft() != null)
            s.push(x.getRight());
        System.out.print(" " + x.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * prints the tree in an inorder fashion.
 * 
 * uses a stack to push left children onto the stack
 * 
 */

public void printInOrder() {
    if (root == null)
        return;

    StackList s = new StackList();
    BSTNode currentNode = root;

    while (!s.isEmpty() || currentNode != null) {

        if (currentNode != null) {
            s.push(currentNode);
            currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
        } else {
            BSTNode n = null;
            n.setElement(s.pop());
            System.out.printf("%d ", n.toString());
            currentNode = n.getRight();
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recursion is very popular when dealing with binary trees, you can use this solution:

```
public int getHeight() {
  return getHeight(root, 0);
}

private int getHeight(BSTNode node, int currentHeight) {
  if (node == null) {
    return currentHeight;
  }

  int rightHeight = getHeight(node.getRight(), currentHeight + 1)
  int leftHeight = getHeight(node.getLeft(), currentHeight + 1); 
  return Math.max(rightHeight, leftHeight);
}
```

Note that it returns height=0 for an empty tree.